# How to prevent select from going below label with Bootstrap?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

This is a very simple and probably scilly question but I can't figure it out. I need a label to be on the same line as the associated select, using Bootstrap CSS. The select keeps 'jumping' below the label if I reduce window's width. How is it possible to control this behaviour using Bootstrap classes? I would need to keep both on the same line, whatever window's width is.

Code sample:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="example">Year</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="example">
      <option>2016</option>
      <option>2015</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

See on JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wiltomap/avg357hc/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is default, but you could also make use of columns inside the form. In the next article in bootstrap columns are used, see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

What you are looking for is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="example" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Year</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="example">
        <option>2016</option>
        <option>2015</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Luuk Skeur! The only problem in your solution is that label is not aligned with the select (I mean vertically) -- See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wiltomap/gbc6Lsxr/).

Comment: I was just wondering why Bootstrap built in CSS could not fix that automatically. Isn't it strange to have to overwrite a piece of CSS?

Comment: They do.. using the class `control-label`, see the edit.